# Docker - Windows containers: How to use custom paths

Tags: docker, filesystems, docker-container, docker-for-windows

I have been trying to figure out where docker is trying to store images when I am doing a docker pull for windows containers but am unable to find the exact location.

Even though I have created Junction links for all the docker files I could find in the C Drive and also configured Hyper-V to store everything in the external drive, when I do a docker pull, it still starts downloading in the C drive which eventually fails as I have no space available there.

Can someone help me here please ? I am trying to do a POC for windows containers and cannot pull down the large images :(

Thanks in advance,
Vishal

Comment: You need to use `graph` for that. Details are here. https://github.com/artisticcheese/artisticcheesecontainer/wiki

Comment: I tried adding graph to the daemon process but it does not seem to use the external drive even after that.

Comment: it worked, Facing some other issues now but I guess I can deal with them in another ticket Thanks